# Are static methods offered by wrapper classes often used?

Tags: java, wrapper, static-methods

I'm curious if static methods of wrapper classes are really helpful.

Which of them are most useful and popularly used? Can you present any must-know tricks involving these methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like `Integer.parseInt`?

Comment: For example. Are there any other interesting and worth-mentioning? I see Java offers quite a lot of them, even `Boolean` type has them :)

Comment: Lots of useful ones.... why do you ask?

Comment: Wrapper methods made me curious. I have C++ background, so it's a new thing to me. I wanted to know if I should be familiar with some of them to be effective. If you know any other nice usages, share with us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compare` methods are useful to handle the primitive counterparts.

```
static int  compare(primitive p1, primitive p2) 
          Compares the two specified primitive values.
```

Possible use:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyClass other){
    return Double.compare(this.myDoubleField, other.myDoubleField);
}
```

Comment: Never used this, it must be new. (Hmm, since 1.4. I'm old.)

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(..)` is used a lot. I don't have statistics though. I've used half of them, but of course they are all useful in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.toString(...)` is used for turning an integer to string without resorting to `"" + i`.

Comment: You can also write `String.valueOf(...)` (which supposedly delegates to this method) - this works for every type, even for `null`.